# return value based on group of rows in sql

Tags: sql, vertica

I have  below data

```
vid   prod
1001  other
1001  other
1001  fixed
1001  fixed
1001  other
1001  fixed
1002  other
1002  mobile
1002  mobile
1002  other
1003  other
1003  fixed
1003  other
1003  mobile
1004  fixed
1004  fixed
1005  mobile
1005  mobile
```

required output

```
vid   prod    prod_2
1001  other   fixed
1001  other   fixed
1001  fixed   fixed
1001  fixed   fixed
1001  other   fixed
1001  fixed   fixed
1002  other   mobile
1002  mobile  mobile
1002  mobile  mobile
1002  other   mobile
1003  other   fixed_mobile
1003  fixed   fixed_mobile
1003  other   fixed_mobile
1003  mobile  fixed_mobile
1004  fixed   fixed
1004  fixed   fixed
1005  mobile  mobile
1005  mobile  mobile
```

Basically i have to write query to create new column 'prod_2' where fixed and others it each row should be updated as fixed, if mobile and others it should be mobile and if fixed, mobile and others it should be fixed_mobile

Comment: i am using vertica

Comment: Looks like a bad idea as if you add a new prod tomorrow, you'll likely forget to also update your prod_2 column.

Comment: its just a temp column that i need for my analysis

Comment: If a vid only have `fixed` and `mobile`, what will `prod_2` be?

Comment: 'Other' is optional it may or may not be present as value, also it can appear after 'Fixed' or 'Mobile'. If 'Others' is not present value still will be same for 'Fixed' and 'Mobile' it should be 'Fixed_Mobile'

Answer (score 1):

I've used [LAG()](https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.0.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/Functions/Analytic/LAGAnalytic.htm) to accomplish this in Vertica using temp tables.

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1
   (
      vid int
      ,prod varchar
   )
   ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;
```

Insert your (vid, prod) data into this table.

Create a second temp table adding a column for the LAG() data

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table2
   (
      vid int
      ,prod varchar
      ,prod2 varchar
   )
   ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

INSERT INTO table2
SELECT vid, prod, 
LAG(prod, 1, 0) OVER 
(PARTITION BY vid ORDER BY vid) as prod2
FROM table1
GROUP BY vid, prod
HAVING COUNT(vid) > 1
ORDER BY vid
```

Table2 now has all of the combinations on the same row.

```
vid     prod    prod2
1001    fixed   other
1001    other   0
1002    mobile  other
1002    other   0
1003    other   0
1004    fixed   0
1005    mobile  0
```

You can limit the results using case logic (my logic might be a bit off here)

```
   SELECT vid, prod, prod2,  
   CASE WHEN (((prod = 'mobile') AND (prod2 = 'fixed')) OR ((prod = 'fixed')  AND (prod2 = 'mobile'))) THEN 'fixed_mobile'
        WHEN ((prod = 'fixed'   OR   prod2 != 'mobile') OR (prod != 'mobile' AND prod2 != 'fixed')) THEN 'fixed'
        WHEN ((prod != 'fixed'   OR   prod2 = 'mobile') OR (prod = 'mobile' AND prod2 != 'fixed')) THEN 'mobile'
        ELSE 'none'
        END AS prod2
        FROM(SELECT vid, prod, prod2
     FROM table2 WHERE prod2 != '0') s1
```

Results:

```
vid     prod    prod2
1002    mobile  mobile
1001    fixed   none
```

Lastly, you can insert this data into another table (table3) and just do a simple join to display the results:

```
   SELECT t1.vid, t1.prod, t2.prod3
   FROM table1 t1
   left join table3 t2
   on t2.vid = t1.vid
```

Obviously you could accomplish the same result with subqueries alone, but this seems a bit cleaner. As you can see below there are some cases where you have two different `vid` cases evaluating true. For example `vid=1003` has `fixed`, `mobile` and `other`.

```
vid     prod    prod3
1001    fixed   fixed
1001    fixed   fixed
1001    fixed   fixed
1001    other   fixed
1001    other   fixed
1001    other   fixed
1002    mobile  fixed
1002    mobile  fixed
1002    other   fixed
1002    other   fixed
1003    fixed   fixed
1003    fixed   fixed_mobile
1003    fixed   fixed
1003    fixed   fixed_mobile
1003    mobile  fixed
1003    mobile  fixed_mobile
1003    mobile  fixed
1003    mobile  fixed_mobile
1003    other   fixed
1003    other   fixed_mobile
1003    other   fixed
1003    other   fixed_mobile
1004    fixed   (null)
1004    fixed   (null)
1005    mobile  (null)
1005    mobile  (null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use union all according to condition

```
select vid,prod,'fixed' as prod2 from t1 where
  t1.vid in(
     select vid from t1     
      where prod in ('fixed','other')
      and vid not in
      (select vid from t1     
      where prod in ('fixed','mobile','other')
      having count(distinct prod )>=3
      group by vid
      )
      having count(distinct prod )>=2
      group by vid
     ) 
union all

select vid,prod,'mobile' as prod2 from t1 where
  t1.vid in(
     select vid from t1     
      where prod in ('mobile','other')
      having count(distinct prod )>=2
      group by vid
     ) 
union all
select vid,prod,'fixed_mobile' as prod2 from t1 where
  t1.vid in(
     select vid from t1     
      where prod in ('fixed','mobile','other')
       and vid not in
       (
        select vid from t1     
      where prod in ('fixed','other')
      having count(distinct prod )>=2
      group by vid
       )
      having count(distinct prod )>=3
      group by vid
     )
```

Comment: i tried above logic, for mobile it is returning 'fixed' because 'Others' is common in both 'Fixed' and 'Mobile' so in first query itself it is updating mobile and others category as 'fixed'

Comment: @Shubham could you please describe little bit more i have not got your point

Comment: like 'Fixed' , 'Others' can also have multiple values within a particular vid

Comment: Put it on sample output

Comment: i have updated sample date and require output. Let me know if this make sense

Answer (score 0):

So, in prod_2, you need:

- 'fixed_mobile' if 'fixed' and 'mobile' exist for a given vid
- 'fixed'  if 'fixed' but not 'mobile' exist for a given vid
- 'mobile' if 'mobile' but not 'fixed' exist for a given vid
- and in any other case, 'none of both' , I suppose, as that can happen, too.

I would use a subquery grouped by vid, returning existence flags for each concerned product per vid. True is greater than False, so the MAX() of a Boolean will tell us if any of the searched values exist. Then, join the main table with that subquery, and evaluate the obtained flags to generate the string for prod_2.

Like in this query (the first Common Table Expression is your input, start with the second Common Table Expression in the WITH clause..)

```
WITH 
-- this is your input, don't use it in final query                                                                                                                                                                                                  
input(vid,prod) AS (
          SELECT 1001,'other'
UNION ALL SELECT 1001,'other'
UNION ALL SELECT 1001,'fixed'
UNION ALL SELECT 1001,'fixed'
UNION ALL SELECT 1001,'other'
UNION ALL SELECT 1001,'fixed'
UNION ALL SELECT 1002,'other'
UNION ALL SELECT 1002,'mobile'
UNION ALL SELECT 1002,'mobile'
UNION ALL SELECT 1002,'other'
UNION ALL SELECT 1003,'other'
UNION ALL SELECT 1003,'fixed'
UNION ALL SELECT 1003,'other'
UNION ALL SELECT 1003,'mobile'
UNION ALL SELECT 1004,'fixed'
UNION ALL SELECT 1004,'fixed'
UNION ALL SELECT 1005,'mobile'
UNION ALL SELECT 1005,'mobile'
)
,
-- start your real WITH clause here ...
existance AS (
SELECT
  vid
, MAX(prod = 'fixed' ) AS fixed_exists
, MAX(prod = 'mobile') AS mobile_exists
FROM input
GROUP BY vid
)
SELECT 
  i.*
, CASE 
     WHEN fixed_exists AND mobile_exists THEN 'fixed_mobile'
     WHEN fixed_exists                   THEN 'fixed'
     WHEN mobile_exists                  THEN 'mobile'
     ELSE                                'none of both'
  END as prod_2
FROM input i
JOIN existance ex USING(vid)
ORDER BY i.vid
;
```

And this is what you get:

```
vid  |prod  |prod_2
1,001|other |fixed
1,001|other |fixed
1,001|fixed |fixed
1,001|other |fixed
1,001|fixed |fixed
1,001|fixed |fixed
1,002|mobile|mobile
1,002|other |mobile
1,002|other |mobile
1,002|mobile|mobile 
1,003|mobile|fixed_mobile
1,003|other |fixed_mobile
1,003|other |fixed_mobile
1,003|fixed |fixed_mobile
1,004|fixed |fixed
1,004|fixed |fixed
1,005|mobile|mobile
1,005|mobile|mobile
```

Happy playing ...